# how can i Translate this vb.net code to c# code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

how can i Translate this  vb.net code to c# code?

```
 Public Function SetPiece(ByVal strGlobal As String, ByVal strNodes As String, ByVal strCode As String, ByVal intPiece As Integer, ByVal strNewVal As String) As Boolean
        Initialize()
        If strGlobal = "" Or strNodes = "" Or strCode = "" Then SetPiece = False
        SetPiece = mobjUtility.SetPiece(strGlobal, strNodes, strCode, intPiece, strNewVal)
    End Function
```

i tried this code but i got an error

```
public bool SetPiece(string strGlobal, string strNodes, string strCode, int intPiece,string strNewVal )
        {
            bool setPiece = true;
            if (strGlobal == "" || strCode == "" )
            {
                setPiece = false;
                setPiece = mobjUtility.SetPiece(strGlobal, strNodes, strCode, intPiece, strNewVal);
            }
            else if (strNodes == "")
            {
                setPiece = false;
            }
            return setPiece;
        }
```

the error is in SetPiece

i solve it guys here's the code:

```html
public static bool SetPiece(string strGlobal, string strNodes, string strCode, int intPiece, string strNewVal)
        {
            
            Initialize();
            if (((strGlobal == "")
                        || ((strNodes == "")
                        || (strCode == ""))))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var obj = mCache.Static("AGSP.UTILS");
            string test = obj.SetPiece(strGlobal, strNodes, strCode, intPiece, strNewVal);
            return obj;
        }
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: Always include exact and full error messages (copy/paste) and indicate the line involved.

Comment: Side note: You probably want to use the short-circuit operator `OrElse` instead of `Or` in your VB.NET code. The respective operator in C# is `||`

Comment: do you want to implement it , or you need a ready tool?

Comment: i tried the codes below but still the error is in SetPiece, it said that because it's a group method and in the return SetPiece it said that object does not contain a definition for SetPiece

Answer (score 4):

Wallah

```
public bool SetPiece(string strGlobal, string strNodes, string strCode, int intPiece, string strNewVal)
{
      Initialize();

      if (strGlobal == "" || strNodes == "" ||strCode == "")
         return false;       

      return mobjUtility.SetPiece(strGlobal, strNodes, strCode, intPiece, strNewVal);
}
```

Also while i'm at it, just go here ([CodeTranslator](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)) instead of asking translation questions. Only ask when you have a problem you cant figure out

Comment: you really save my day TheGeneral i really can't read this old system and translate it to new system thanks for the link

Comment: You do know that the word is "voila" - French for "there it is" - right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool SetPiece(string strGlobal, string strNodes, string strCode, int intPiece, string strNewVal)
{
    Initialize();
    if (strGlobal == "" | strNodes == "" | strCode == "")
        SetPiece = false;
    SetPiece = mobjUtility.SetPiece(strGlobal, strNodes, strCode, intPiece, strNewVal);
}
```

Comment: the original piece of code doesn't return. So doesn't mine.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli the original code returns. It uses a "feature" of vb where instead of an explicit `return` you can assign the return value to the name of the function (`SetPiece=... `)

Comment: That's a feature of vb6, I didn't know it was inherited. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your original VB code has a flaw that you may not be aware of.
The assignment `SetPiece = False` has no effect.  VB allows assignment to the method name temporary variable, but the function doesn't return at that point.  If no actual 'Return' statements are encountered, then the value of the temporary SetPiece variable is returned when the function exits (when either `End Function` is encountered or the first `Exit Function`). In your sample, only the final assignment to SetPiece is relevant.  The original flaw can be fixed by changing your 'If' to an 'If/Else'.

The actual C# equivalent, with the original flaw being a little more obvious is:

```
public bool SetPiece(string strGlobal, string strNodes, string strCode, int intPiece, string strNewVal)
{
    bool tempSetPiece = false;
    Initialize();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strGlobal) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(strNodes) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCode))
        tempSetPiece = false; //no effect

    return mobjUtility.SetPiece(strGlobal, strNodes, strCode, intPiece, strNewVal);
}
```